# Was the BrEng term "coloured" derogatory in the 1970s?

Tags: british-english, pejorative-language, offensive-language, dialogue

[image: face of a beautiful young actress with wild afro hair, dressed in 1970s clothes]

> SAM
>   Look... I owe it to myself to say this to you, okay? Leave Tony Crane. Just go far away from him. He's gonna ask you to marry him and he's gonna make you a business partner.
>
> EVE
>   Is that what this is all about? Does it bother you that much? **A coloured bird** with a bit of power?
>
> <sup>BBC One's *[**Life on Mars**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yIMP6-KBSCs)* series 2, episode 1</sup>

For those who have not watched the BBC TV series a very brief synopsis:
After an accident, Sam Tyler a Detective Chief Inspector in 2006, wakes up in 1973. Now a detective inspector, he has a love-hate relationship with DCI Gene Hunt—one of the most politically incorrect characters in the history of British television. Sam Tyler doesn't know if he's mad, in a coma or if he's travelled back in time. All he wants is to go back home to the future.

---

In view of the fact that the TV series is set in 1973, a time when sexism, racism, and homophobia was rife and the British general public had only started condemning those acts of behaviour.  I was taken aback to hear the following lines:
*Does it bother you that much? A coloured bird with a bit of power?*

I was only ten years old in 1976 and I remember the noun *Black* (or adjective *black*) was considered derogatory, almost a taboo, whereas *coloured* was the "polite" term used to describe anyone whose skin was dark-coloured. But childhood memories can play tricks, so I'm not absolutely certain.

Was the term [coloured](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/coloured) derogatory in the 1970s? Did Eve call herself "coloured" because she knew it was offensive or did British black people call themselves that?

Nowadays, I know it's the other way round, and I'm pretty sure  that [Benedict Cumberbatch](http://www.bbc.co.uk/newsbeat/30994775) does too. But what about the 1970s? Shouldn't the actress line have been:

> Does it bother you that much? A **black bird** with a bit of power?

Comment: I had a friend, back in the 70's (English born, from a Barbadian family) who referred to herself as "coloured".  I'm sure she found it the right term to use and in no way derogatory.

Comment: @Centaurus but then why does Eve call herself "bird"? That was and always has been terribly sexist.

Comment: Certainly in the US the terminology was undergoing a change in the 70s.

Comment: 'Life on Mars' probably doesn't strive over hard to keep to its standards of unacceptability. And 'A coloured bird with a bit of power' flows better.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - In general (although a few exceptions can always be found) members of a "disfavored" category are allowed to use terms which are offensive when applied to them by those outside their category. The use of the N-word in rap is a classic example, as is Chris Rock's use in his comedy routines about 15 or 20 years ago. In using the term to describe herself, she is essentially claiming that he (Sam) would use the term. In any case, in 1973 Manchester the term may well have been in wide use regardless of our current judgements as to its sexism.

Comment: I'm sure the downvotes have nothing to do with English Language. It's just sheer prejudice from people who believe certain subjects shouldn't be discussed, even if you are just discussing English Language. I got quite a few downvotes when I posted a question on a slang word for erectile dysfunction.

Comment: Coloured:  In Britain it was the accepted term until the 1960s, when it was superseded (as in the US) by black. The term coloured lost favour among black people during this period and is now widely regarded as offensive except in historical contexts. http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/coloured

Comment: @Josh61 Yes, but in 1976 I was only ten years old living in London and I'm pretty sure "coloured" wasn't considered so offensive then. The most taboo words were nxxxer, along with cxxn. You NEVER openly said those words unless you were unashamedly racist, and/or a skinhead.

Comment: If I could join the melee, +1 for a provocative OP. That said, I doubt that, in their private self, anyone really accepts (without a flinch) being "generalized", especially by reference to the colour of their skin. I know I don't "accept" (without some dismay) being called "white". The practice is such a generalization, objectification, and so superficial. In a way it's akin to people referring to me as a "cripple" (+bad) or as "handicapped" (-bad). All these labels for "Other" i.e., not one of us, not OK (our kind). All so loaded with baggage, and yet it's impossible at times to avoid them.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I think the 70s was period  of transition where the term 'coloured' was gradually replaced by  'black'. Language evolves slowly so no surprise that the term during those years was still perceived as neutral while gradually being replaced 'black'.  A fair degree of personal perception regarding the nuances of words must be taken into consideration as well!!

Comment: Coloured people vs black people (BrE) : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=coloured+people%2Cblack+people&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccoloured%20people%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cblack%20people%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Josh61 if *coloured* was an offensive term, would [British Parliament papers](https://books.google.it/books?id=tiE6AQAAIAAJ&q=%22coloured+children%22&dq=%22coloured+children%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=C1XfVNiWNIvvaPSjgvgG&ved=0CDIQ6AEwBA) , 1974, have written about *coloured children*? A lot of the Ngram hits are about S. Africa, the links at the bottom of Ngram Books have to be read carefully. Actually, I think that document is conclusive proof...

Comment: I didn't say it was, I just said the term was in a transition period...probably the question is..when did the term 'coloured' started to be perceived as offensive?

Comment: From my 60+ US perspective, many of the “Coloreds (used as a noun) Only” signs I saw in the 50s & through the mid-60s were erected/sanctioned by local/state/sometimes even federal agencies, so I’m not sure that usage of a term by the government proves anything. Here, the transition from the highly offensive use of "Colored(s)" as a Noun "back" to its “enlightened’ use as an adjective through the 70s, whether modifying “bird/children/minorities/people/race”, was an important, yet middle-ground baby step pending the subsequent leap from "colored," as adjective, to B/black, as noun or adjective.

Comment: Here we are again. Could this help? "Clearly, Hansen's intentions were honourable. But his ignorance is breathtaking. ***Is he really unaware that the word "coloured" has been verboten since the mid-70s?***  It's considered offensive for two reasons. First, it implies that all the world's different ethnic groups can be divided into two categories, white people on the one hand, and "coloureds".... http://blogs.telegraph.co.uk/news/tobyyoung/100125547/should-alan-hansen-apologise-for-using-the-word-coloured-on-match-of-the-day/. This could fit with the 1974 Br. Parliament papers.

Comment: @Mari-LouA (Feb 13): Was 'bird' offensively sexist?  Was the use in the title an attempt to disarm the barb?"The Liver Birds is a British situation comedy, set in Liverpool, North West England, which aired on BBC1 from April 1969 to January 1979,"  Google page  //Liver Birds.

Comment: @Josh61 See, I would have said that the term *coloured* became "taboo" by the early-eighties. I wonder when the shift from *coloured* to *black* occurred.

Comment: Most evidence appears to confirm the shift occurred towards the end of the 70's/beginning of 80's. ***Warning: Why using the term 'coloured' is offensive***: In the UK the term is, at best, seen as old fashioned and "something your gran might say".
But it's also regarded as a highly offensive racial slur which recalls a time when casual racism was a part of everyday life. ***It was also seen as an acceptable word to use in much of the UK until the 1960s and 1970s.***  http://www.bbc.co.uk/newsbeat/article/30999175/warning-why-using-the-term-coloured-is-offensive

Comment: @Josh61 post that, and I'll upvote it. The writers were probably more concerned with shocking today's audience than with being chronologically correct.

Comment: I don't think you can be chronologically "correct" regarding this issue. I mean that it takes time for a term to change its connotation ( from neutral to offensive in this case). so referring to a period of at least half a decade to refer to this change is reasonable and gives a more "correct" indication of the period in question ( end 70's beginning 80's) according to the sources I have found.

Comment: @Josh61   The TV series is set in 1973, Manchester, an industrial city which at the time, presumably, lacked a certain awareness and sensibility towards racial issues. The programme reminds viewers just how politically correct the UK used to be. Hence my question!

Comment: I cannot comment on political correctness, and I probably misundestood your quesiton.

Comment: @Josh61 The TV series is set in 1973, Manchester, an industrial city which at the time, presumably, lacked a certain awareness and sensibility towards racial issues. (I meant to say) **The programme reminds viewers just how politically INcorrect the UK used to be.** Hence my question! And btw I would still upvote a post that quoted the BBC article.

Comment: I'm surprised this question wasn't closed as being *primarily opinion-based*. (Of course, it cannot be closed now, as it has a bounty.) Whether something was derogatory at the time depends on the speakers and hearers then (and the context), and it might well have been community-dependent. Whether someone *now* thinks that it was derogatory back then is even more opinion-based. FWIW, I doubt that much light will be shed here, and I see little light so far.

Comment: @Drew WS2's answer is the best so far because it is based on an eye-witness account. He is British and he has always lived in the UK, I was hoping for another testimony, and also an answer as to how British blacks called themselves back then. I don't see how this is an opinion-based question, we're talking about forty years ago, not seventy or a hundred. I'm very tempted to write a letter to the screenwriters of *Life on Mars*, asking for clarification,  but I wouldn't know where to begin. :)

Comment: You have 1 person's claim of a remembrance of 1 person's experience. If it helps you, OK, but it's not helpful for the site. For something like checking whether a word is/was derogatory, you need more than that to go on, including checking with different groups/communities (since the term labels a group) to see how the term was perceived by them. Was "girl" derogatory if applied to a mature woman in the 40s? The answer might depend on whom you ask, and on the context. And it might depend on an analysis of just what it means for a term to be derogatory (however perceived).

Comment: @Drew and that's why I set up the bounty! Please take note that I did not accept any answer, and I think this question is *useful* to the site.

Comment: @Josh61 I think the change from *coloured* to *black* was something that occurred over quite a long time period, beginning, I would suggest, in the late sixties, and not being fully established till about 1980. I clearly remember being hesitant about using the word *black* in the early years, because many (especially older) people still thought of it as a term of abuse. When I lived in Australia in the mid-seventies I discovered they were many years behind Britain, in this regard - their having had the White Australia Policy through the fifties and sixties.

Comment: @WS2 - late 60's late 70's-beginning of 80's is in fact the period of time that the sources I have mentioned refer to,

Comment: @Josh61 In that case your understanding is exactly the same as mine.

Answer (score 11):

Thinking back, I believe ***coloured*** was originally a euphemism, used to avoid the word ***black*** which British people thought, probably correctly at the time, was offensive.

I believe the demise of ***coloured*** as an acceptable term dates from the emergence of ***black***, mainly from the American black community, as a term of pride. With the growth in the use of ***black***, I think ***coloured*** came to be seen, by some people (not all), as a patronising slur, a 'kind' way of not referring to a person's blackness, treating the fact as though it were a handicap.

Comment: So back in the 70s *coloured* wasn't considered offensive? Right? I think you're spot on in saying *coloured* was a euphemism. The "patronising slur" aspect, seems to ring a few bells too. Do you think (or know) a British black person in the 70s would have called themselves "coloured" or "black"?

Comment: 'Back in the 70s' 'coloured' was the PC word to describe people of African / Caribbean ancestry. It was not derogative or offensive.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - My recollection is that, in the 70s in the US, the terminology was beginning to change.  "Colored" was being deprecated and replaced with "black".  There was a period of about 10 years when any word you used was guaranteed to insult someone.

Comment: @HotLicks Yes I think that the experience you mention in the US followed virtually the same pattern as it did in Britain - or more correctly vice-versa. (On this matter we were definitely influenced by you). However where I think everyone here is slightly mistaken is in believing the transference from *coloured* to *black* as the politically correct term began in the 70s. I think the change began in the 60s, at around the time of the 'Black Power' movement in the US - Malcolm X and all that. Didn't MLK celebrate the idea of 'blackness'? hadn't there been a body known as  (cont fwd)

Comment: B Fwd- known something like AACP (American Association of Coloured People) that had been the main vehicle of the Civil Rights Movement.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Re did I know someone? I remember my first managerial-type job, in which I recruited my own staff, which I began in 1969, in South London. The senior management of the company and its parent group were very prejudiced against employment of Indians, (and occasionally West Indians/Africans) and I had to fight a battle with my bosses (since it was predominantly Indians who were presenting themselves for employment). They would refer to the Indians as 'coloureds' (and worse).

Comment: One last question, as far as you can remember, West Indians and people of African origins, how did they "call" themselves back in the early 70s?

Comment: +1 WS2 - you 'breakdown' the transition of the relative terms well. As to the "main vehicle of the Civil Rights Movement" that was the National Association for the Advancement of Colored People (NAACP), which was founded in 1909-1910 in New York City by a group of white & black intellectuals. United in their opposition to the "gradualism" preached by Booker T. Washington, the NAACP leaders sought, first, to make whites aware of the need for racial equality.[NAACP](http://www.history.com/topics/naacp)

Comment: @WS2 - As Little Eva notes, it was/is the NAACP -- National Association for the Advancement of Colored People.  (But as you note, some people used "colored" as a derogatory term for any non-Caucasian.  Pretty much any term chosen would be hijacked by the bigots.)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Can't remember! Possibly Jamaicans, Trinidadians, or Nigerians, Ugandans etc. At that time the West Indies had a fantastic cricket team, probably best in the world. When they played England, huge numbers used to turn up at the ground with their musical instruments and play calypsos, during the match! In London that Caribbean community is heavily concentrated south of the river, in the Brixton, Lambeth, Vauxhall area. I was there the other day, in the Elephant and Castle. There is such a focus on Asians in Britain these days that I had quite forgotten about the Caribbeans.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I feel most indebted to you for your munificence in transferring to me 200 bounty points. Not being as adept at using the system as your good self, I was not aware that such a procedure was possible. Anyway - thank you for the kind gesture - which, if I may say so, typifies your generosity of approach, on this site.

Answer (score 4):

In this context, I think Eve was deliberately using derogatory terms. She's expressing her perception of Sam's point of view, so she uses language that reflects what she thinks he thinks of women and blacks.

Comment: It's a very possible interpretation, but you need to backup your theory with some facts or references. Otherwise you're just providing an opinion.

Comment: How do I back up an interpretation with "facts"? If she were talking to me, that's how I would interpret what she was saying.

Comment: I think the nature of the exchange makes it obvious that she's trying to be confrontational. It wouldn't serve the narrative purpose if the words didn't have these negative connotations.

Comment: In 1976 I was only ten years old living in London and I'm pretty sure "coloured" wasn't considered so offensive then. There wasn't a shortage of taboo word or insults for Blacks in that era, pretty much they are the same today with the exception of *black*, which was considered degrading then. Consider the actor Cumberbatch who was born in 1976, he's never struck me as being racist in the slightest, so my instincts tell me that as a child he must have been "taught" to say *coloured* because that was the proper word to use. They're only conjectures on my part, I know.

Comment: Shouldn't the line have been: Does it bother you that much? A B/black bird with a bit of power? I haven't seen the series yet, so all I have to go on are the printed words and the set-up you've provided. I believe your answer lies in the tone of Eve's delivery, and when I use my mind's ear I hear Eve issuing an ironic, maybe even sarcastic, challenge: Does it bother you that much? i.e., are you--a big powerful white man--so threatened by a small, powerless minority female (double minority). I agree with Barmar's evaluation that his answer it can't be backed-up, **it's all in Eve's delivery**.

Comment: @LittleEva The delivery is in fact said in a tone of exasperation and lightly veiled sarcasm, but that's the point of my question. If the derogatory term was *black* in the 1970s (UK), why would she use the "PC" term instead? I did try to look for that specific clip but I didn't find any.

Comment: Speaking only for the situation in the US, "Black" didn't have broad currency prior to ca 1973 - before then it was largely restricted to certain subcultures (college campuses, African-American communities) I initially encountered the humans in question as "colored people" But as WS2 noted, that was just a method of avoiding expressing the implied derogatory, often in "mixed" company. To my mind "colored" never was acceptable to African Americans (though it *was* preferable to other terms) who understood it as code--not for "Black"--code for the really bad word.

Comment: I'm going to find Life on Mars and watch for myself. Sounds like an interesting premise. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: The delivery definitely adds to the sense. So even if that wasn't a particularly derogatory term at the time, using it in this way still suggested the idea of colored = inferior. And of course, the writers were dealing with the fact that this would be viewed by a 21st century audience, not a 70's audience.

Comment: This Ngram query shows the two terms intersecting in 1968 and by 1972 “Black” is twice as prevalent as “Coloured”, reaching its apogee in 1986, after which “Black” goes into a steep decline to below 1972 levels (?) [BrE: Coloured People, Black People](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=coloured+people%2Cblack+people&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=1&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccoloured%20people%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cblack%20people%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: In AmE the same two terms intersect in 1966 and by 1970 “Black” reaches its apogee and is twice as prevalent as “Colored” then displays a steep decline. (?) [AmE: Colored People, Black People](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=colored+people%2Cblack+people&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=1&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccolored%20people%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cblack%20people%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @Barmar  I've upvoted your last comment, I think they knew they would cause an uproar if they used a highly-charged term. But that bugs me, because it doesn't reflect the reality of that decade. Please look at this [British Parliament paper dated 1974](https://books.google.it/books?id=tiE6AQAAIAAJ&q=%22coloured+children%22&dq=%22coloured+children%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=C1XfVNiWNIvvaPSjgvgG&ved=0CDIQ6AEwBA). Would a derogatory term have been used and published.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm not qualified to" say whether 'coloured' was considered offensive at that time, though I certainly remember it being used. But maybe the emphasis of the question lies equally on the sexist 'bird'. Try substituting a different epithet - "A scouse/posh/Scots/fat bird with a bit of power." I think she is assuming this how she is viewed, and in her case the most commonly used word was probably 'coloured'.

Comment: @Mynamite the question is  which term, *black* or *colo(u)red*, was considered more offensive in the 1970s. A derogatory term, in my opinion, fits better with the "sexist" bird epithet. Or did the writers of the show deliberately choose *colo(u)red* because it has a more negative impact on today's audience.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Some answers here suggest that 'black' was becoming the preferred term in the early 1970s, but that took a long time to seep through into everyday usage. I know some older people who would still use 'coloured' or even 'negro' without any racist intent but simply because these were the words they were brought up with - MLK used both these words as respectful terms in his speeches. If this clip was historic, documentary footage I'd say definitely 'coloured' was the most commonly used word at that time, but as to what the writers believed or intended, who can say?

Comment: @Mynamite the show "Life on Mars" was made in 2006...

Comment: @Mari-LouA  Yes I know, I watched it. What I'm trying to say is that I think 'coloured' was the most commonly used word at that time, certainly in the area and amongst the kind of people that the show depicts, and was not necessarily offensive in itself. Like many similar epithets it could be straightforwardly descriptive, or derogatory depending on context eg 'Irish people' is OK but 'the bloody Irish' is not. You're asking whether the writers intended to shock us - perhaps they did, but if so they were mistaken IMO. This word was normal for the time.

Answer (score 4):

Based on my recollection of the 80s and 90s in a white to multicultural bit of London I would say "not really". There were certainly white people who objected but they were progressive, even hippie-ish types in other ways.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

When dismantling segregation was still casually status quo in the western hemisphere, as was the case in the 1970's, several words were used as substitutes for overtly racist adjectives and the word 'Coloured' was accepted as one of those substitutes to be used in/for/with polite company.

In January of this year (this is being written July of 2015) a United Kingdom entertainment celebrity gained inadvertent attention with his use of the word "coloured(s)" in a public interview.

So.

Why is/was the word 'coloured' seen as offensive in the West? Simple. It reflected an attitude of racial boundary and entitlement casually accepted at the time; in effect someone is white, or they are a person not white, and thereby colored or *of* color ( ... 'colour' and 'coloured' in the UK).

Coulored was a shadow word, a synonym, one of those polite words used in polite company, on the television, and perhaps with your Gran, instead of those niggardly, spiteful, offensive words of hate, superiority, and disentitlement, which as in the case of the example you cited, came to be embraced and used **because** people didn't like it

Curiously? In Africa, the word "Coulored" has an entirely different meaning. The word 'Coulored' -- spelled thus, and outside the shared UK/US  word coloured/colored word dichotomy -- is a term referring to specific  South African ethnic peoples.

From your original link:
"Coloured referring to skin colour is first recorded in the early 17th century and was adopted in the US by emancipated slaves as a term of racial pride after the end of the American Civil War. In Britain it was the accepted term until the 1960s, when it was superseded (as in the US) with the use of the word 'black'."

Comment: *Coloureds* in South Africa were (and maybe still are) people of Asian descent - not Africans. During the years of *apartheid* there were special rules applicable to them. Perhaps the most celebrated *coloured* was one Basil D'Oliveira, a cricketer who was ineligible to play for the national team because of his colour. To cut a very long story short he came to Britain and was selected to play for England. But the South Africans refused to play England if there were 'coloureds' in the English team. It caused huge division in Britain, before we eventually refused to accept such a condition.

Comment: The story of [Basil D'Oliveira](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basil_D%27Oliveira) is well worth reading.

Comment: When I moved to London (from the English provinces) in the 1960s I remember being shocked to see advertisements for accommodation which said such things as *NO COLOUREDS, NO IRISH*. ('Polite people' didn't even talk about gays and lesbians in those days)

Comment: @WS2 ...from the link you provided:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coloured

Answer (score 2):

Here's part of an answer given by Michael Foot to a question that he was asked during a Radio 4 programme that was broadcast on 10 June 1973 (which was within just a few months of the setting of the TV programme mentioned by the questioner), called *Politics in the 70's*. This programme was noteworthy because it placed Foot in conversation with Enoch Powell, who was regarded by many as supporting inflammatory views about black people, while Foot was an advocate of social equality.

Here, Foot is referring to Powell's contribution to the debate on race, especially the oratorical elements of this contribution.

> I believe the way in which he [Enoch Powell] puts his case on this
>   subject is destructive of the community in the sense that more and
>   more of the ... er ... coloured people in this country are born in
>   this country; they are citizens of this country. They should have
>   absolutely equal rights with everybody else in this country, and if
>   they are singled out as being a section of the community that is
>   disruptive or that should be sent back to places where in fact they
>   weren't born,  that is disruptive of the community itself.

The long hesitation before he chose the word "coloured" was the only major disfluency in this section of the programme. Given Foot's views, he clearly wasn't searching for a word that was derogatory but one which was not. That difficulty cannot have been due to Foot's unpreparedness on the subject.

I was 9 years old at the time the story was set, and it accords with something in my own memories of the era. In my school at that time, there were very few black children and when teachers were openly racist to them in class, it raised few eyebrows at the time. Race was such an emotive issue that a speaker could feel (or sound) awkward no matter which word they used. "Coloured" was probably the most common term that I heard used without any pejorative intent during the 70s (especially the earlier parts of the decade). Also, there were plenty of epithets of varying intensity to choose from should one intend insult. But it's impossible to get the full linguistic picture without being aware that the very subject was itself taboo.

Returning to the question about the TV episode and its dialogue, it was of course television drama and all kinds of things may have influenced the script. I'd suggest that the average viewer in 1973 wouldn't have thought that the word "coloured" was more derogatory than any other word, but you'd have to ask the script writer what the dramatic intent was.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and thoughtful answer and testimony. It helps confirm my belief that the term *coloured* wasn't considered derogatory or offensive in the early 1970s. Your chronological reference is also pertinent.