# Does the word "brownie" have the same implication as the N-Word?

Tags: meaning, dialogue

I was watching the latest episodes of The X-Files a couple of weeks ago and in one of the [episode](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=the-x-files&episode=s10e05) a middle aged white man driving down the road in Texas stares at a Mid Eastern/Asian guy at a traffic stop and says:

> Looks like we got a visitor. A little ***brownie***. Are we in the
>   wrong country then? Huh?

So in the above situation, does the word brownie have the same implication as the N-Word? I did do some research on this subject albeit on the Internet only, but could not find any authoritative source that helps me to compare and consequently figure out the implication.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ethnic_slurs_by_ethnicity

Comment: In Britain a *Brownie* is a junior Girl Guide, the female equivalent of a cub-scout. They wear brown dresses, on which they sew all their achievement badges. And they look very sweet.

Comment: @WS2 - Same in the US.  But traditionally, words such as "brownie", "blackie", and "darkie" have been used refer to dark-skinned people from several racial groups.  At one time the terms were considered to be "polite" (when compared to the "N word"), but they've been classed as pejoratives for over 50 years now.  ("Brownie" was not a common one when I was growing up, but I suspect it was common in the US Southwest where it would have referred to Mexicans and South Americans.)

Comment: I believe [this former question on the use of *coloured*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/227434/was-the-breng-term-coloured-derogatory-in-the-1970s) is relevant.

Comment: And [this on the RAF's most famous dog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nigger_(dog)) may be of interest.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it does not. In this context, "brownie" is clearly intended as a racial slur referring to skin color, but the word can also be used in a number of perfectly innocent ways:

- [A chocolate dessert](http://allrecipes.com/recipes/1562/desserts/cookies/brownies/chocolate-brownies/)
- [A small mythological creature in English folklore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownie_(folklore))
- [A young Girl Scout](http://www.girlscouts.org/en/our-program/grade-levels/what-brownies-do.html)

None of these usages are treated as tainted by association - one need not use circumlocutions when asking for a chocolate brownie at a bakery, for instance. By contrast, "nigger" is treated as highly offensive, to the extent that even some unrelated words that sound similar (e.g, "niggardly") are often avoided.

Comment: And it's been a long time since I heard someone refer to a Brazil nut as a "nigger toe".

Comment: @Hot Licks, Sadly, I heard this just the other day...

Answer (score -1):

The same implication, but weaker.  The *X-files* writers wish to shock the audience, but Fox's standards won't allow it, so the writers settle for the tepid "**brownie**".  In 1948, similar publishing standards obliged Norman Mailer to alter *The Naked and the Dead*; that WWII novel's expletive-prone soldiers thus use the *ad hoc* near-swear "[**fug**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Naked_and_the_Dead#.22Fug.22)".

Movie and cable-TV writers suffer a kindred dramatic weakness: addiction to hyperbolic swearing and its saccharine gravitas.  To promote a routine studio potboiler *up* from PG or G, scripts are marinated in salty wordages.  Whenever these productions air on broadcast TV, where FCC standards apply, that language is replaced with sound-alikes, at times so carelessly that it's comedic gold.  Only in the edited for broadcast television version of *Lethal Weapon* does Mel Gibson growl "We bury the **[funsters](http://listoftheday.blogspot.fr/2013/11/creative-movie-dialogue-edits-of-day.html)**!"

Comment: I think these claims require evidence if they are to be believed.